# C++ MFC EditBox Handling Double Click

Tags: c++, mfc

The scenario I have is as follow:

1. I have a CDialog class that contains two EditBox controls, lets say it's IDC_EB1 and IDC_EB2.
2. I want to be able to listen to a Double Click event on IDC_EB1 and IDC_EB2 to open up a FileDialog and display the selected file location on IDC_EB1 and IDC_EB1.
3. IDC_EB1 and IDC_EB2 is doing through the DDX Control mechanism and stored into their respective member variables.
4. The member variables type is of CMyEdit (derived from CEdit) in order to handle double click event.

The dialog runs and I was able to open up a FileDialog when I double click on IDC_EB1 or IDC_EB2 to browse. The problem is within CMyEdit, I no longer know which EditBox triggered the double click event in order to display the file path selected from the FileDialog.

What would be a good way to resolve this problem? I'm running Visual Studio 2010 SP1.

PS: There is the MfcEditBrowse Control which would solve the problem above nicely but it doesn't fit my need because the plan is to reuse this CDialog window at various stages in my program and apparently you cannot invoke DoModal more than once on a Dialog that has MfcEditBrowse Control. the MfcEditBrowse Control i nthat Dialog will throw an assertion failure (known problem apparently according to what I found on Microsoft documentation).

Comment: *"apparently you cannot invoke DoModal more than once"* That's not true. A modal dialog temporarily disables the parent dialog, until it is closed, you can call it again and again.

Comment: *"known problem apparently according to what I found on Microsoft documentation"* - Please provide a link as reference.

Answer (score 0):

> I no longer know which EditBox triggered the double click event in order to display the file path selected from the FileDialog.

You can use CWnd::ChildWindowFromPoint(point) which will return the clicked child control within the body of OnLButtonDblClk().

Comment: You have to derive a class from `CEdit` to catch `WM_LBUTTONDBLCLK` message for the edit control. `ChildWindowFromPoint` would be redundant.

Comment: No, you don't need to derive a class from CEdit instead OnLButtonDblClk of CDialog derived class. if you have derived a class from CEdit then you will have separate event handling for both the child control.

Comment: The parent window will not receive mouse messages for the child window in this scenario. Your solution is not clear.

Comment: @BarmakShemirani It is clear that he is going to implement either in CDialog or CEdit derived class to perform double click operation by providing  OnLButtonDblClk implementation. There he can call CWnd::ChildWindowFromPoint(point) to get which button got clicked and initiate the appropriate dialog. As he mentioned CMyEdit derived from CEdit so OnLButtonDblClk of CMyEdit class.

Answer (score 0):

1. You know the ID inside the double click handler. Just call [GetDlgCtrlID](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cwnd-class#getdlgctrlid) from the message handler.
2. You can easily add some data to CMyEdit to make it easy to identify the control for the action of the double click
3. You can send a WM_COMMAND message upon the double click from the CMyEdit to the parent and the parent handle the rest. The parent knows the control by its Id and should know what to do.

Comment: *"You know the ID inside the double click handler..."* - That's no correct. The [CWnd::OnLButtonDblClk](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cwnd-class#onlbuttondblclk) message handler has the following signature: `afx_msg void OnLButtonDblClk( UINT nFlags, CPoint point)`. The control ID is not immediately available there.

Comment: Added hint to GetDlgCtrlID